# Prevent OpenGL ES from destroying canvas when orientation is switched

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, surfaceview

As far as I know, when the orientation of an Android device is changed, Open GL ES destroys the onSurfaceCreated() and similar methods and restarts them. In other words, when the orientation is changed, everything gets reset as if it just started because as far as opengl es is concerned, it did. The issue I'm having is I don't want it to wipe the render surface clean. I want it to continue, only in landscape. To reiterate: It stays the same, all the matrices and object positions, only now the orientation is different. I'm not sure how I'd go about this. I thought of maybe preserving the last state before rotation and then applying it to the new render surface - Would this be a good way to about it? So I guess my question is: How would I keep OpenGL ES(2.0) from clearing the render surface(or the illusion of) when the screen orientation is switched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL ES does not destroy contexts or surfaces during orientation changes.  The `View` hierarchy does do this; `GLSurfaceView` is particularly fond of releasing everything it can find.

The `onSurfaceCreated()` callbacks are associated with `Surfaces` and `Views`.  When the orientation changes you go through the activity lifecycle events, which tear down the `View`, and they in turn tear down the `Surface`.  If this didn't happen, and you continued to render into the same `Surface`, then everything you did would appear to be rotated 90 degrees.  (Remember, `SurfaceView` surfaces are sent directly to the system compositor, not composited with the UI by the application.)

The usual practice is just to let everything get torn down and then build it back up again.

If this doesn't work for some reason, I would recommend that you do your rendering off-screen and then blit the texture to the current surface.  You can see an example of this in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "Double decode" activity, which renders into a pair of `SurfaceTextures` that it connects (and re-connects) to a pair of `TextureViews`.  Another way to do the same thing would be to create an FBO, render into that, and blit that to your `SurfaceView` (you can see an example of FBO setup / blit in Grafika's "Record GL app" activity).

Comment: I see. Thanks.So you suggest just letting it build back up again on orientation change? I  working on a project for someone and they want the animations to not be reset on orientation change. They want it to continue. Should I just tell them it'd be better to have it be reset?

Comment: Having the *surface* reset and having the *animations* reset are different things.  Your app can continue from wherever it was even though the surface has changed (keeping it mind that, because of the orientation change, the surface dimensions may be different afterward).  For example, in Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/), the game state is independent of the `GLSurfaceView` (which aggressively tears everything down).  I added a brief pause to let the player adjust, but there doesn't have to be one.

Comment: So I should do the animations and keeping track of positions outside of the surface view, that way it doesn't get reset?

Comment: Yes.  Use the SurfaceView subclass just for rendering, keep all the app state in a different class.